# Differential Equations Solving for Critical Points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x'' +20x - 5x^3 = 0$

Did a quick substitution and found the critical points to be $(2,0), (-2,0)$, and $(0,0)$. However, when solving for the eigen values of the corresponding matrix found that the eigen values were both $0$. Unclear what to do from now.
My matrix was $\big\{\{0,1\},\{5x^2-20,0\}\big\}$.

Comment: How are you writing a matrix for a non-linear ODE? Also, please do not use tags that are irrelevant.

Comment: Substituted y = x' to make it linear (y' = 5x^3 - 20x, x' = y)

Comment: Nope. The $x^3$ makes it non-linear.

Answer (score 3):

We are given

$$x'' +20x - 5x^3 = 0$$

We can write this as a system

$$\tag 1 \begin{align} x' &= y \\ y' &= 5x^3 - 20 x \end{align}$$

Finding critical points by simultaneously solving $x' = y' = 0$ yields

$$(x, y) = (0, 0), (2, 0), (-2, 0)$$

Finding the Jacobian of $(1)$

$$\text{jac}(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 15 x^2 - 20 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Evaluating the eigenvalues of the Jacobian at each of the three critical points

At $(0,0)$, we have a center as the eigenvalues are

$$\lambda_{1,2} = 2 i \sqrt{5},-2 i \sqrt{5}$$

At $(2,0)$, we have a saddle as the eigenvalues are

$$\lambda_{1,2} = -2 \sqrt{10},2 \sqrt{10}$$

At $(-2,0)$, we have a saddle as the eigenvalues are

$$\lambda_{1,2} = -2 \sqrt{10},2 \sqrt{10}$$

A phase portrait would look like

[image]